# Flatten a nested dict structure in Python

Tags: python, hash-map

For some post-processing, I need to flatten a structure like this

> ```
> {'foo': {
>           'cat': {'name': 'Hodor',  'age': 7},
>           'dog': {'name': 'Mordor', 'age': 5}},
>  'bar': { 'rat': {'name': 'Izidor', 'age': 3}}
> }
> ```

Each bottom entries will appear as a row on the output. The heading keys will appear each row, flattened. Perhaps an example is better than my mediocre explanation:

> ```
> [{'age': 5, 'animal': 'dog', 'foobar': 'foo', 'name': 'Mordor'},
>  {'age': 7, 'animal': 'cat', 'foobar': 'foo', 'name': 'Hodor'},
>  {'age': 3, 'animal': 'rat', 'foobar': 'bar', 'name': 'Izidor'}]
> ```

I first wrote this function:

```
def flatten(data, primary_keys):
    out = []
    keys = copy.copy(primary_keys)
    keys.reverse()
    def visit(node, primary_values, prim):
        if len(prim):
            p = prim.pop()
            for key, child in node.iteritems():
                primary_values[p] = key
                visit(child, primary_values, copy.copy(prim))
        else:
            new = copy.copy(node)
            new.update(primary_values)
            out.append(new)
    visit(data, { }, keys)
    return out

out = flatten(a, ['foobar', 'animal'])
```

I was not really satisfied because I have to use `copy.copy` to protect my input arguments. Obviously, when using `flatten` one does not want its input `data` to be altered.

So I thought about one alternative that uses more global variables (at least global to `flatten`) and uses an index instead of directly passing `primary_keys` to `visit`. However, this does not really help me to get rid of the ugly initial copy:

```
keys = copy.copy(primary_keys)
keys.reverse()
```

So here is my final version:

```
def flatten(data, keys):
    data = copy.copy(data)
    keys = copy.copy(keys)
    keys.reverse()
    out = []
    values = {}
    def visit(node, id):
        if id:
            id -= 1
            for key, child in node.iteritems():
               values[keys[id]] = key
               visit(child, id)
        else:
            node.update(values)
            out.append(node)
    visit(data, len(keys))
    return out
```

I am sure some Python magic will help in this case.

Comment: Where does `'foobar'` and `'animal'` come from? They appear nowhere in your calling example. Shouldn't it be `out = flatten(a, ['foobar', 'animal'])` instead?

Comment: Absolutely, my mistake !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both algorithms recurse using the length of `keys` to stop, so I am going to assume that the nested dictionaries always have the same level of nesting too. If your input *can* be of the form:

```
{'foo': {
          'cat': {'name': 'Hodor',  'age': 7},
          'dog': {'name': 'Mordor', 'age': 5}},
 'bar': { 'rat': {'name': 'Izidor', 'age': 3}},
 'baz': 'woops',
}
```

then your approach can't handle it and neither will mine.

---

I quickly stopped trying to understand how your algorithm work and started to think about how I would implement it myself. This indicates that:

- your algorithm is not that trivial;
- it is poorly documented.

You should at least have comments indicating why you use some approaches: reversing the `keys` and iterating over them in decreasing order, storing your group names/values (`values[keys[id]] = key`) as you go into nesting levels and updating the last dictionary when you reach it…

Speaking about updating the last dictionary, note that `data = copy.copy(data)` does not protect your `node.update(values)` to modify the original `data` in place. You either need to use `copy.deepcopy` or to change the updated dictionary (create a new one and update it with both `node` and `values`).

---

Now let me show you an other approach. Rather than wrapping a function that access global variables (this is what `visit` look like) into `flatten`, you can make `flatten` the recursive function by splitting `keys` into its `head` and `tail` part. When there is no element left, you won't be able to do it and you can stop the recursion by returning the `data` you're on: this is one of the most nested dictionaries.

Otherwise, you can iterate over the key/values pairs, flatten the values using the `tail` as a new set of `keys` and then, build a list out of the flattened values and the `{head: key}` dictionary.

To make things a bit more efficient, I'll use generators instead of building lists, so you’ll want to change your calls from `out = flatten(a, ['foobar', 'animal'])` to `out = list(flatten(a, ['foobar', 'animal']))` (calls of the form `for flattened in flatten(a, ['foobar', 'animal']):` don't need to be changed though):

```
def flatten(data, group_names):
    try:
        group, group_names = group_names[0], group_names[1:]
    except IndexError:
        # No more key to extract, we just reached the most nested dictionnary
        yield data.copy()  # Build a new dict so we don't modify data in place
        return  # Nothing more to do, it is already considered flattened

    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        # value can contain nested dictionaries
        # so flatten it and iterate over the result
        for flattened in flatten(value, group_names):
            flattened.update({group: key})
            yield flattened
```

I also changed `keys` to `group_names` to be able to use the generic names `key` and `value` when iterating over `data`.

---

In case the input data can ever contain less nested levels than the amount of items in `group_names`, you'll reach a point where `data.iteritems()` will raise and `AttributeError`. You can catch that if you so choose:

```
def flatten(data, group_names):
    try:
        group, group_names = group_names[0], group_names[1:]
    except IndexError:
        # No more key to extract, we just reached the most nested dictionnary
        yield data.copy()  # Build a new dict so we don't modify data in place
        return  # Nothing more to do, it is already considered flattened

    try:
        for key, value in data.iteritems():
            # value can contain nested dictionaries
            # so flatten it and iterate over the result
            for flattened in flatten(value, group_names):
                flattened.update({group: key})
                yield flattened
    except AttributeError:
        yield {group: data}
```

So

```
a = {
    'foo': {
        'cat': {'name': 'Hodor',  'age': 7},
        'dog': {'name': 'Mordor', 'age': 5},
    },
    'bar': {
        'rat': {'name': 'Izidor', 'age': 3},
    },
    'baz': 'woops',
}

list(flatten(a, ['foobar', 'animal']))
```

will return

```
[{'animal': 'woops', 'foobar': 'baz'},
 {'age': 5, 'animal': 'dog', 'foobar': 'foo', 'name': 'Mordor'},
 {'age': 7, 'animal': 'cat', 'foobar': 'foo', 'name': 'Hodor'},
 {'age': 3, 'animal': 'rat', 'foobar': 'bar', 'name': 'Izidor'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this will surely help me in the future. So I will retain these two basic concepts. First, the use of generators and second, your elegant way of shifting a list `element, a = a[0], a[1:]`. That said I am still wondering how the `try`/`catch` exception handling will impact the performances. I may want to do some tests about this.

Comment: @nowox It is even neater in Python 3: `element, *a = a`; it raises `ValueError` though. Exception handling is pretty good in python. I doubt that `if group_names: ... else: yield ...` will be faster.